# Asynchronous Server Socket with multiple clients

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, serversocket, asyncsocket

when I was testing Asynchronous Server Socket program from multiple workstation causing below issue
case 1:c
1.Running out of working threads if I send a string data like 500 times from each workstation parallel( right now sending data only from two workstations to server).

case 2: below happens only few time
2. usually it write 490 bytes but somehow it fail to write data with 54 bytes in log.

case 3:
when I send 500 times different string data from one workstation to server and  after sending 50 or 100 messages or data, it shows following log:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host: socket programming happens

below sample program I am using it now.

```
using System;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Sockets;  
using System.Text;  
using System.Threading;  

// State object for reading client data asynchronously  
public class StateObject {  
    // Client  socket.  
    public Socket workSocket = null;  
    // Size of receive buffer.  
    public const int BufferSize = 1024;  
    // Receive buffer.  
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];  
// Received data string.  
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
}  

public class AsynchronousSocketListener {  
    // Thread signal.  
    public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);  

    public AsynchronousSocketListener() {  
    }  

    public static void StartListening() {  
        // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.  
        // The DNS name of the computer  
        // running the listener is "host.contoso.com".  

   ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 8);
   ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(8,4);

        IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());  
        IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];  
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 11000);  

        // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,  
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );  

        // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.  
        try {  
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);  
            listener.Listen(10);  

            while (true) {  
                // Set the event to nonsignaled state.  
                allDone.Reset();  

                // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.  
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");  
                listener.BeginAccept(   
                    new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),  
                    listener );  

                // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.  
                allDone.WaitOne();  
            }  

        } catch (Exception e) {  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");  
        Console.Read();  

    }  

    public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        // Signal the main thread to continue.  
        allDone.Set();  

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.  
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);  

        // Create the state object.  
        StateObject state = new StateObject();  
        state.workSocket = handler;  
        handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
    }  

    public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        String content = String.Empty;  

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket  
        // from the asynchronous state object.  
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;  
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;  

        // Read data from the client socket.   
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);  

        if (bytesRead > 0) {  
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.  
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(  
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));  

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read   
            // more data.  
            content = state.sb.ToString();  
            if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) {  
                // All the data has been read from the   
                // client. Display it on the console.  
                Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}",  
                    content.Length, content );  
                // Echo the data back to the client.  
                Send(handler, content);  
            } else {  
                // Not all data received. Get more.  
                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,  
                new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);  
            }  
        }  
    }  

    private static void Send(Socket handler, String data) {  
        // Convert the string data to byte data using ASCII encoding.  
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);  

        // Begin sending the data to the remote device.  
        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0,  
            new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);  
    }  

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {  
        try {  
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
            Socket handler = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;  

            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.  
            int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);  
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);  

                    } catch (Exception e) {  
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);  
            handler.Close();  
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());  
        }  
    }  

    public static int Main(String[] args) {  
        StartListening();  
        return 0;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: "1.Running out of working threads if I send a string data like 500 times from each workstation parallel( right now sending data only from two workstations to server)." You just found a complicated way to make a Denial of Service attack. Severs have limited resources to process resquests and limit resources to store requests. So of coruse you run into that limit sooner or later. Espeically if the Computer is not actually server grade (wich means Core counts in multiples of 64)

Comment: To add to the above comment, although your code might be asynchronous, reading and writing to/from ports are blocking actions. You could run multiple servers listening on different ports to distribute the work to multiple processes with their own thread groups, otherwise the single server process will reach it's thread limit while they're all blocked from execution. 

You might want to think about what realistic amount of traffic you are expecting in your use case, then design a working solution around that.

Comment: @EricMagers Now I am processing minimum number of data string like 30 with maximum number of threads and still I see  Failed to read data from the socket, Error Message = An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote. is it because of reading and writing to ports are blocking actions or anything wrong in my code  Note: not running of threads

Comment: @rremo When this error message is thrown it should come with an error code which will help narrow down the issue. Typically this isn't an asynchronous issue, but a connection issue (one end of the connection closing before it's supposed to).